# How do I determine which service pack Visual Studio is running?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, servicepacks

How do I determine which service pack (if any) Visual Studio is running? Right now I'm trying to determine if a machine is running VS2008 or VS2008 SP1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found it. It's not the version number as I initially expected.

Go to Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio and it's under Installed Products:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
>   Professional Edition - ENU Service
>   Pack 1 (KB945140)

I had to scroll through the list to find it.

Comment: My VS doesn't show what you mentioned. Instead it shows "HotFix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU(######) ######". is there any other way to check the version??

Comment: Also is Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 are 2 different things?

Answer (score 1):

Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio